# JPA entitymanager different identities

Tags: java, jpa

I have an application with EJB and JPA:

`ActionService`

```
@Stateless
public class ActionService {

    @EJB
    private ActionDao actionDao

    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager em;

    public Action create(Action x) {
        return actionDao.create(x);
    }

    public foo businessLogic() {
        em.createQuery(...)
    }

@Stateless
public class ActionDao {

    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager em;

    protected T create(final T t) {
        this.em.persist(t);
        return t;
    }
}
```

After debugging I realized that the both `EntityManager` (`ActionService`, `ActionDao`) have different identities. Is this a problem/can this become a Problem?

Comment: No, depending on the JPA provider you'll get a fresh EntityManager for every transaction so that's normal.

Comment: So, I won't run in any strange transaction issues when dealing with two EntityManagers?!

Comment: Define strange ;) - No, you shouldn't run into issues stemming from that.

Comment: It would be a "strange" problem if the service and the DAO have a different transaction created for them, because that shouldn't be happening. In the flow of the code posted ActionService will cause a transaction to be started, and ActionDao.create() will adopt that existing transaction.

Comment: Yeah, I would have thougt so

Comment: @matthias did you check that you don't actually get a proxy for the EM? Since a session bean could be reused with different transactions the EM should be replaced (or acts as a proxy itself, depending on the JPA implementation). In Hibernate for example, both calls to `em` should be redirected to the same Hibernate session at least.

Comment: I use EclipseLink. How can I check if it is the same session?

Comment: Me personally I wait for something to blow up, that at least is a guarantee that something is actually wrong. And you can be sure that when transactionally something is wrong in your code, you're going to know it. I don't see anything wrong in the posted code, its too flat and simple to allow any mistake. Did you leave relevant annotations out perhaps?